# Appunta AR markers overlaps, change the orientation of eyeview but make activity in portrait mode only

Tags: android, dictionary, augmented-reality, screen-orientation

I am developing an application where I am using three views of the data.
1.) ListView 2.) ARView 3.) MapView.

For Geo-AR I am using "Appunta AR-engine".
Its very cool and simple AR-engine.

Previously I was using metaio SDK. But there is lot of problem with this SDK on many handsets.Here is the screen developed using Metaio.

....

This is the screen I have developed using Appunta AR-engine. But here evrything is collapsed.

Is there any way we can arrange them in visible order.

One more thing, when I make Activity as portrait only(in manifest).
AR eyeviw does not go to landscape mode.

How can we change the orientation of EYEView and radarview, by keeping the activity in portrait mode only.

[screen developed using appunta](http://tardis1.tinygrab.com/grabs/1c4f0c1df3d721faad96bc0d31263d5b01325b3fa3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the appunta library :)

Currently the platform does not support ordered drawing by itself (noticed for future releases), but you can implement by yourself just sorting the points by distance before drawing them in the preRender method of the eyeview (this method is executed once per frame before drawing the points) or setting the z-order for each point while drawing them.

About the eyeView, this should work without issues in portrait mode, in fact, the sample is rotable.

I suspect you refere to the camera view, my advice is frankly do not use it. I had to implement a "rotable" camera view for project requirements, but it's horrid and it's a real resource eater. Just implement a simple non-rotable camera view like [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Just one more thing can we make the "eye view" in landscape and portrait mode without changing the orientation of whole screen.

Comment: I have build an dining offer app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icicibank.culinarytreats and used the metaio.

But it crashes on some phones and perform poorly sometimes.

Comment: Yes you can. Just need to take control of the orientation and draw the labels "rotated" following this orientation. Check your camera app, it's what it does, because rotating the "camera" is too expensive in computation time as you have to shut down and start it.

Comment: Is there still active developing going on in Appunta ?